# Use foldr to define map in Haskell,

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and try to understand the **map** function.

I understand the following so far.

```
map::(a->b)->[a]->[b]
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

But I **don't understand** following definition:
Use **foldr** to define map

```
map'::(a->b)->[a]->[b]
map' f = foldr ( (:).f ) []
```

Can anyone explain the above map' definition and why it is **same as map**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at [the source of `foldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr):

```
foldr k z = go where
    go []     = z
    go (x:xs) = k x (go xs)
```

Now let's compare the definition of `map` to the definition of `go` above:

```
map f []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

It looks very similar, doesn't it? Let's rewrite the second clause to pull out the part that combines `x` with the recursive call's result:

```
map f []     = []
map f (x:xs) = (\v vs -> f v : vs) x (map f xs)
```

Now the parallel is very clear; we can even write some names to crystallize the parallel:

```
map f []     = z              where z = []
map f (x:xs) = k x (map f xs) where k = \v vs -> f v : vs
```

Just substitute `go` everywhere you see `map f` in the above and you'll see that the definitions are identical! So in the spirit of DRY, we can try to reuse `foldr` for the above:

```
map f = foldr (\v vs -> f v : vs) []
```

That gets you the big idea on how to get from `map` to `foldr`. Getting all the way to the definition you gave is then just some syntax tricks. We'll concentrate on the function argument to `foldr` now:

```
\v vs -> f v : vs
= { writing the infix operator prefix instead }
\v vs -> (:) (f v) vs
= { eta reduction }
\v -> (:) (f v)
= { definition of function composition }
\v -> ((:) . f) v
= { eta reduction }
(:) . f
```

So using this chain of reasoning, we can reach the final form

```
map f = foldr ((:) . f) []
```

Comment: beautiful and fantastic

Answer (score 3):

An alternate answer, hopefully more accessible to some people.

`foldr f z xs` replaces every `:` in `xs` with `f`, and `[]` with `z`. So

```
 a : b : c : d : []
```

becomes

```
 a `f` b `f` c `f` d `f` z
```

Now let's substitute values from the definition of `map'`.

```
a `(:).f` b `(:).f` c `(:).f` d `(:).f` []
```

(I'm stretching the Haskell syntax a bit).

Now,

```
a `(:).f` as
```

is the same as

```
(:) (f a) as
```

which is the same as

```
f a : as
```

Continuing wit this transformation, we get

```
f a : f b : f c : f d : []
```

Hey, this looks like straight `map f` applied to `[a,b,c,d]`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand

```
foldr (:) []
```

the other one is just applying function `f` before cons, therefore equivalent to map